# What do you think about that diagram?

Tags: class, associations, uml, diagram

Could you please tell me if my diagram is correct?
I especially care about relations between `PaymentService` and `Customer`,
`Payment`, `Customer`

I guess that:

```
   class Customer {
     private List<Payment> payments;
     //..
     public boolean pay() {
       return PaymentService.pay(this.payments);
       // calling the static method of the class PaymentService
     }
   }

   interface Payment {
     // knows nothing about Customer
   }

   class PaymentService {
     public static boolean pay (List<ayment> payments) {
       // the magic here is return result
     }
   }
```

---

UPD: Now, I noticed that why I use static member, but it does not touch my question.

What is the common way to construct payment systems (It looks like a general task)?

---

I guess that the FFCustomer should have only one account.
And an account exists only while an FFCustomer exists.

[image]

UPD:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty close. Make the association to Payment unidirectional. Make the account property an association end. In general, attributes should only be typed by datatypes, not classes. You are also missing an operation in the Payment interface.

Comment: Actually, while I don't guess waht is the operations are need there. Now, I think about make it as abstract class that will keep amount of money that needs to pay.

Comment: When you change the original diagram, the answer will make no sense to anyone else. Nobody else can benefit from this.

Comment: But, I am yet not find he answer. Thank'u for directing me. But how I can make new question , if this is not yet completed.

Comment: I would keep the original diagram that was in your question. If you like, you could also show the improved diagram as an update.

Comment: Say me, please about corectness of relation between Customer and Payment classes  in the current image

Comment: I am not sure, but I tried to restore to state that was before

Comment: That association looks okay, although an X usually isn't shown unless *both* ends are unnavigable. Maybe your tool can only draw it that way.

Comment: I chosen the unspecified case, and it is reduced the X.
I have three cases for unnavigability: true, false, unspecified