# Domain Modelling Practice

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis, domain-model

I have an interview related to domain modelling coming up. Do any of you know of a site or resource that has practice questions and solutions available? I can't seem to find interview questions related to domain modelling with class diagrams and UMLs.

I understand domain modelling can be done in many ways, but it would be nice to have a good reference to at least ensure that I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: This is pretty close, but no practice questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29462410/2596664

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34256880/2596664

Comment: See also http://agilemodeling.com/essays/initialRequirementsModeling.htm#DomainModel